# Android - Radial Chart implementation

Tags: android, plot, charts, native, radial

Is there a native way or library to create a chart as this in Android?

I would like to render this natively rather than loading up a webview with some web library

[image: Radial chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other people wondering, I did it with progressBars using a custom shape background, you can select the background, the "gray" area, and the progress, and even animate them.

Comment: Please can you share it how you achieved it ?

Answer (score 0):

[AnyChart](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android) contains this functionality.

There is a [very comprehensive sample snippet](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/anychart/sample/charts/CircularGaugeActivity.java), the core of which is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart_common);

    AnyChartView anyChartView = findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view);
    anyChartView.setProgressBar(findViewById(R.id.progress_bar));

    CircularGauge circularGauge = AnyChart.circular();
    circularGauge.data(new SingleValueDataSet(new String[] { "23", "34", "67", "93", "56", "100"}));

    anyChartView.setChart(circularGauge);
}
```

Which, along with a few hundred customisation lines, results in something similar to:

[image: radial chart]

Comment: You have to purchase it for commercial use or get the license for educational purpose. https://www.anychart.com/buy/non-commercial-license/